# How to embed a cmd to pyqt5 application

Tags: python, cmd, pyqt5, embed

I tried codes below, but it seemed not work as normal. I cannot use embedded cmd whatever I did. It looks like decorations. I mean I just want to use the cmd like the ordinary one. Here, I paste the code,  and any advice would be greatly appreciated.
I develop this app on Python 3.7.3 conda environment, Window10.

```
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import win32gui

from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QWindow, QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMdiArea, QSplitter, QTextBrowser
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from win32com import client
from win32gui import GetWindowText, EnumWindows,SetForegroundWindow
class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.p = QProcess()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.mainSplitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainSplitter)
        self.mainSplitter.addWidget(QTextBrowser())
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.runExe()
        EnumWindows(self.set_cmd_to_foreground, None)
        hwnd1 = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        #hwnd1 = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe")
        print(hwnd1)
        window = QWindow.fromWinId(hwnd1)
        container_widge = self.createWindowContainer(window, self)
        container_widge.setFocusPolicy(Qt.TabFocus)
        container_widge.setFocus()
        container_widge.setWindowTitle("ain")
        container_widge.setFont(QFont("Times New Roman"))
        container_widge.setGeometry(500, 500, 450, 400)
        #container_widge.setFocusPolicy()
        container_widge.activateWindow()
        container_widge.acceptDrops()
        container_widge.grabMouse()
        container_widge.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.mainSplitter.addWidget(container_widge)
        self.showMaximized()
        #self.setGeometry(200, 200, 700, 700)
        #self.show()
    def runExe(self):
        shell.run("cmd.exe")
        time.sleep(1)
    def set_cmd_to_foreground(self, hwnd, extra):
        """sets first command prompt to forgeround"""
        if "cmd.exe" in GetWindowText(hwnd):
            print(hwnd)
            SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
            return
    def run_script(self, shell, scripts):
        """runs the py script"""
        shell.SendKeys(scripts+"{ENTER}")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    shell = client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    #ex.run_script(shell, "python -m pip list")
    #ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey Tao Li - welcome at Stack Overflow :) Could you explain in more detail what you try to achieve and what is the problem? What do you mean by "I just want to use the cmd like the ordinary one."? What cmd? What ordinary one?

Comment: Cmd is Windows command line just like *xtem* terminal on Linux. While I have embedded cmd into an app developed via pyqt5, I could't  use the embedded cmd to input comand or output results.

Comment: I dont this you can use windows cmd inside your pyqt application but there is another way for doing it. Just create your pyqt application just like cmd and input the commands and run them internally using any library like ```os, subprocess```

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to run comand in python, but actually, I want to provide a cmd-like interactive interface within the application.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this I got it from this [blog](https://pythonbitsnpieces.blogspot.com/2023/02/creating-debugging-window-with-pyqt.html):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess, QTextStream
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, 
QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.process = QProcess(self)
      self.output = QTextEdit(self)
      self.input = QLineEdit(self)
      self.run_command_button = QPushButton("Run Command", self)

      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      input_layout = QHBoxLayout()
      input_layout.addWidget(self.input)
      input_layout.addWidget(self.run_command_button)
      layout.addLayout(input_layout)
      layout.addWidget(self.output)
      central_widget = QWidget(self)
      central_widget.setLayout(layout)
      self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

      self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.read_output)
      self.run_command_button.clicked.connect(self.run_command)
      self.process.start("cmd.exe")

   def read_output(self):
      stream = QTextStream(self.process)
      self.output.append(stream.readAll())

   def run_command(self):
      command = self.input.text() + "\n"
      self.process.write(command.encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      window = MainWindow()
      window.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```